# Chrome: onBeforeUnload method does not use given text

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, window

This is my code

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  var msg = 'test';
  e.returnValue = msg;
  return msg;
};
```

As you can see the window should display a prompt with the text "test" on it when the window is closed.

However, the confirm contains the followin text: "Changes you made may not be saved".

Other Browssers like Edge (tested) seem to work with this.

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onbeforeunload's custom string support is removed in google chrome 51+, and (according to the chrome release notes) has been removed in safari 9.1+ and firefox 4+.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/chrome-51-deprecations?hl=en#remove-custom-messages-in-onbeforeload-dialogs